# Ubuntu touch channel for Nexus7 2013

Tags: ubuntu-touch

What's the recommended channel for Ubuntu touch on Nexus7 2013. Ubuntu touch is working with channel devel, but this results also has a UI for phone. It seems to be a image of phone and not a tablet. So I am not sure whether devel is the correct image for the the Nexus7. 
In addition, I am also annoyed by the GPS which will is enabled all the time.
Regards, Marcel

Answer (score 0):

For now, it thinks the **Nexus 7 (2013)** is a phone (with SIM card), regardless of which model.

*That will change soon, with tablet-specific features to be added.* Please be patient.